# How to implement CSS in elements within a given id or class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
<div id="chart-id-149" class="big_number_total">
  <div class="superset-legacy-chart-big-number  no-trendline" style="height: 98px;">
    <div class="header-line" style="font-size: 18px; height: 49px;">
      <span>30</span>
    </div>
    <div class="subheader-line" style="font-size: 3px; height: 30px;">% Conversions</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Kindly note that I want to reference *subheader-line* class for the id: *chart-id-149*. So the condition should be the text within id of *chart-id-149* and class *subheader-line* should have the colour blue.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
#chart-id-149.subheader-line {
    color: blue;
}
```

But I see no effect, please do let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: You need space before class: `#chart-id-149 .header-line`

Comment: please note you say you wish the `.subheader-line` to contain blue text but the css is targeting `.header-line`

Comment: @LukasJ thanks, yeah this sorted my problem. Ramon de Vires thanks, made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descendant elements are selected with a space in CSS, so you need:

```
#chart-id-149 .header-line
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing a space before dot (.)

```
#chart-id-149 .header-line
{
    color: blue;
}
```